# Get one string with space first and get another after tabs

Tags: c, regex, text

I want to get strings from a .txt file, reading lines that each has name and phone number. and two \t characters are between names and phone numbers.

Example:

```
name\t\t\tphone#
thomas jefferson\t\t054-892-5882
bill clinton\t\t054-518-6974
```

The code is like this;

```
FILE *f;
errno_t err;
treeNode *tree = NULL, temp;
char input, fileName[100];

//get file name
while (1){
    printf("Enter input file name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", fileName, 100);
    //f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(err = fopen_s(&f, fileName, "r"))
        printf("Cannot find file!\n");
    //if (f == NULL)
    //  printf("Cannot find file!\n");
    else
        break;
}

//save info into BST
fscanf_s(f, "  NAME         Phone #\n", 20);
while (fscanf_s(f, "%[^\t]s\t\t%[^\n]s",
    temp.name, temp.phoneNo, 50, 30) != EOF)
    bstInsert(tree, temp.name, temp.phoneNo);
fclose(f);
```

treeNode is a binary search tree struct, and bstInsert is a function to add a struct containing 2nd and 3rd parameters to a binary search tree.

after I get the name of the file with scanf_s, code stops at the fscanf_s statement, showing below on the debugger;

`temp.name: invalid characters in string.`

temp.phoneNo: ""

I don't know how `[^\t]` or `[^\n]` works exactly. Can anyone let me know how I can deal with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: the website doesn't show me some texts as i want.. \n characters are at the end of each line.

Comment: In the edit box there is a "?" icon in the top right. It shows you help on how to format code/.... Also capitalizing words correctly would make things more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Can anyone let me know how can I deal with this problem?"* I am no fan of `scanf` and family, so I deal with the problem by using different methods. Following your lead of using `fopen_s` and `scanf_s` I have used the "safer" version of `strtok` which is `strtok_s`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE *f;
    errno_t err;
    char *pName, *pPhone;
    char input[100], fileName[100];
    char *next_token = NULL;

    // get file name
    do{
        printf("Enter input file name: ");
        scanf_s("%s", fileName, 100);
        if(err = fopen_s(&f, fileName, "r"))
            printf("Cannot find file!\n");
    } while (err);

    // read and process each line of the file
    while(NULL != fgets(input, 100, f)) {               // has trailing newline
        // isolate name
        pName = strtok_s(input, "\t\r\n", &next_token); // strip newline too
        if (pName == NULL)                              // garbage trap
            pName = "(Error)";
        printf ("%-30s", pName);

        // isolate phone number
        pPhone = strtok_s(NULL, "\t\r\n", &next_token); // arg is NULL after initial call
        if (pPhone == NULL)
            pPhone = "(Error)";
        printf ("%s", pPhone);
        printf ("\n");
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output using a file with your example data:

```
Enter input file name: test.txt
name                          phone#
thomas jefferson              054-892-5882
bill clinton                  054-518-6974
```